# When appending value to slice, value is different from original value

Tags: go

consider this piece of code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Part(11))
}

func Part(n int) string {
    enumResult := [][]int{}
    enum(n, n, []int{}, &enumResult)
    fmt.Println(enumResult)
    fmt.Println(40, enumResult[40])
    return ""
}

var abc int = 0

func enum(n int, top int, pre []int, result *[][]int) {
    var i int
    if n > top {
        i = top
    } else {
        i = n
    }
    for ; i > 0; i-- {
        tempResult := append(pre, i)
        if n-i == 0 {
            /*  if tempResult[0] == 3 && tempResult[1] == 3 && tempResult[2] == 3 && tempResult[3] == 2 {
                tempResult = append(tempResult, 12345)
            }*/
            fmt.Println(abc, tempResult)
            abc++
            *result = append(*result, tempResult)
        } else {
            enum(n-i, i, tempResult, result)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code

I append value '[3,3,3,2]' to 'enumResult'

but If I check the value of 'enumResult' then '[3,3,3,1]' is appear

it`s index is 40 =>enumResult[40]
(other value is correct)

I don`t know why this is happening
Can you explain to me why?

Comment: Please come up with a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed due to `append`.

There are two thing about `append`. First is, that `append` doe not necessarily copy memory. As the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices) specifies:

> If the capacity of s is not large enough to fit the additional values,
>   append allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits
>   both the existing slice elements and the additional values. **Otherwise**,
>   **append re-uses the underlying array.**

This may cause unexpected behavior if you are not clear. A playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/7A3JR-5IX8o

The second part is, that when `append` does copy memory, it grows the capacity of the slice. However, it does not grow it just by 1. A playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/STr9jMqORUz

How much `append` grows a slice is undocumented and considered an implentation details. But till Go 1.10, it follows this rule:

> Go slices grow by doubling until size 1024, after which they grow by
>   25% each time.

Note that when enabling race-detector, this may change. The code for growing slice is located in `$GOROOT/src/runtime/slice.go` in `growslice` function.

Now back to the question. It should be clear now that your code did `append` from a same slice with sufficient capacity due to growth of the slice from `append` before. To solve it, make a new slice and copy the memory.

```
tempResult := make([]int,len(pre)+1)
copy(tempResult,pre)
tempResult[len(pre)] = i
```